# Add vertical swipe to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a horizontal swipe of my UIPageViewController that moves between 3 view controllers. I want to add a Vertical swipe onto this to add a extra level to the navigation.

However I have not found a solution to do so. I have tried adding a simple

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

But this doesn't work as I presume the UIPageView overrides this.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using pageview controller in my app. I have added same code as yours. and my swipe up event is working fine.

change this line in your code

```
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing with storyboards,this tutorial would be helpful

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/